# MATLAB leverage() calculation

Tags: matlab

I have the data that looks like the one in variable X. The function leverage() gives values that are different than the matrix calculation below. I am wondering why?

```
X = randn(1000,1); X(900) = X(900)*20;
h1 = leverage(X);
h2 = diag( X*inv(X'*X)*X') %This is from Mathworks website
sum(h1-h2) %This is equal to 1 - why?
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The example from first link.

```
load hald
X = ingredients
X =

     7    26     6    60
     1    29    15    52
    11    56     8    20
    11    31     8    47
     7    52     6    33
    11    55     9    22
     3    71    17     6
     1    31    22    44
     2    54    18    22
    21    47     4    26
     1    40    23    34
    11    66     9    12
    10    68     8    12

    
h1 = leverage(X);
h2 = diag( X*inv(X'*X)*X');

[h1, h2]
ans =

    0.5503    0.4812
    0.3332    0.2841
    0.5769    0.1236
    0.2952    0.2371
    0.3576    0.3417
    0.1242    0.1163
    0.3671    0.3636
    0.4085    0.3818
    0.2943    0.1899
    0.7004    0.6788
    0.4255    0.3733
    0.2630    0.1925
    0.3037    0.2362

sum([h1, h2])

ans =

    5.0000    4.0000
```

p from h1 is not euqal p from h2.
Because in first case the count of parameters linear additive regression model is 5 (`p = size(X,2) + 1`).
But with Hat Matrix approach are use only 4 columns of input matrix (`p = size(X,2)`)

If you will use other regression models ('quadratic' or 'purequadratic'), then p from h1 will `p = size(X,2) + 2`, but p from h2 will stay the same `p = size(X,2)`

Therefore, in first case p is related with count of regression parameters. In Hat Matrix case p is fixed and always equal `size(X,2)`. Looks like in second case the processing method "nothing known" about type of regression model.

Comment: Why are you posting clarifications of your answer as additional answers? Please just edit the original answer if you are adding explanation.

Comment: I am sorry, will to do that in future

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I understand the rules here, but your comment/post was useful.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `sum(leverage(data))` return `p+1` value, where `p` is the number of parameters in the model (you can check it with example data from [webpage](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/leverage.html))

`sum` of Hat Matrix diag.elements return `p` value, "Because the sum of the leverage values is p" (the citation from [webpage](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hat-matrix-and-leverage.html))

Comment: Sorry, am I missing some info here? The second link shows that both sum to p.